# Creating a hyperlink out of data retrieved from a db and using get()

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I'm playing around with a form I've made and everything working smoothly. My goal right now is I'm retrieving some rows from my db and displaying them as a summary on a separate page however, I want the rows returned to be fashioned as a hyperlink so when you click them it will open a more detailed summary of that row. A snippet of my code is as follows,

```
$query = "SELECT species, energy FROM root.records";
/**
* Check to see if query was successful
*/
    if ($query) {
     //echo "Success\n";
    }
    else {
        //echo "Error\n";
    }

if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($species, $energy);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf ("Species: %s | Energy: %s", $species, $energy);
        printf("<br/>");
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

this is retrieving and printing the contents of the rows returned by that query. Now, should I just edit one of those `printf` statements to embed as an href link? In my mind this should work but I'm having trouble figuring out how I will know which entry is being chosen to get a more fine description on since theres no way to determine which rows are being returned. I was considering doing something with `$_GET` but I'm only familiar with `$_POST`. Perhaps something like this,

```
<a href="index.php?species=wolf">
```

and using this information from GET to pull all of the detailed records on that species?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, then that should work fine.

Loading a page to the browser is in itself a GET request - consider the URL of this very question for example and you can see that we have several parameters being passed in the URL.

You could pass the species information as a query string - take this one from a Wordpress plugin that I've been building

wordpress.local/wp-admin/plugins.php?page=my_news_settings

Looking at the values of the $_GET request for that URL, we can see:

```
array (size=1)
  'page' => string 'my_news_settings' (length=16)
```

so you could essentially pass the species to the URL and then use that to retrieve the further information from the database.

**Important note about $_GET**

As mentioned previously, GET requests expose parameters, so make sure you are always sanitising and validating anything that is passed (You don't want someone adding something nasty into that query string and into you database).

Also for this reason, ensure that you never pass passwords or sensitive information in a GET request.

In this instance, I'd just echo out the link html

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    printf ("Species: %s | Energy: %s", $species, $energy);
    printf("<br/>");
    echo '<a href="https://url/?species='.$species.'">read more about '.$species.'</a>';
}
```

I hope this answer helps and I've understood - good luck :)

Comment: Yes I agree. The way to do it using a href tag and GET sound easier I'm just having a hard time implementing it and I think its because of how I'm choosing to print the initial summary of the information. Printing the results of the query whilst making them a hyperlink to a more detailed description of that particular species.

Comment: Updated my answer for you :) That should create you a link which when clicked, you can use the $_GET values to access the 'species' key of the array :)